# ACID transactions in delta lake

Tags: pyspark, delta-lake

I use Azure Databricks with Python Notebooks to transform data and store them in one Delta Lake table. There are multiple such notebooks run through Azure DataFactory and they are executed in parallel, therefore it might happen that even 15 different pyspark processes will try to write data to one output delta lake table at the same time.

I can think of two ways of doing it, but maybe I am just complicating things?:

A) All processes will write outputs to their own temporary tables and then I will create a notebook that will run after all processes are done and will collect data from temporary tables into the main output table.

B) I will partition the table by column that identifies the process uniquely. That should make sure that any process writing data will write into different subfolders. But still, there is a common metadata file about data version that could become corrupt?

What can I do to make sure that data of all processes writing in same time will be stored in the ACID way?

Comment: This will be helpful: [What are ACID guarantees on Azure Databricks?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/lakehouse/acid)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a strategy that combines partitioning the table and leveraging Delta Lake's built-in concurrency control features.

- You partition by a Unique Process Identifier: This significantly reduces the risk of write conflicts. Each process writes to its own partition, and effectively isolate the data and minimize chances of interference
  This means faster and more efficient writes: each process deals with a smaller, separate section of the table.
- Delta Lake's Concurrency Control: Delta Lake can handle concurrent writes. It uses optimistic concurrency so it allows multiple processes to attempt to write at the same time.
  If conflict, Delta Lake resolves it automatically with one write succeed and the others retry.
  So your data integrity is maintained without manual intervention.